# PopupWindow android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите tutorial на русском по PopupWindow, не смог найти. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

- [статья в официальной документации по Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow) (англоязычная).
- [статья в блоге Александра Климова](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/popupwindow.php) (русскоязычная).